# What species of moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Please help identify this species found at home.  I think it's a moth. Size is about 1 cm.

Is it harmful if found at home?

Location: urban home in Hong Kong

[image]

<sup>Click photo for full-size picture</sup>

[image]

Comment: Please update the question with your location.

Comment: Its size is about 1 cm.

Comment: Thanks for the size. Please add your location. What country/state/province do you live in? What kind of area is your home in (urban vs wooded vs farm etc.).

Comment: Hong Kong, of sub-tropical climate ;  urban home, a flat on the 10th flor of a multi- storey building